# Why does the Zener diode's simulation model differ so much from datasheet specifications?

Tags: simulation, zener, pspice, reverse-breakdown

I was trying to design a circuit with a Zener diode by using its datasheet specifications and noticed there was a very big difference between the design and the simulated circuit. After inspecting the Zener diode model used by PSpice for the ZY91 diode shown in the figure below, I noticed it differed a lot from the [datasheet](https://www.tme.com/Document/b472b5b915333c97aa338a8bb7b82c01/zy1.pdf) specifications for the same diode. From the specs we can see that \$r_z = 40 \Omega\$ for the test current \$ I_z = 5 \mathrm{mA}\$, which is the value of \$r_z\$ I used to design the circuit. However, from the figures of the PSpice model for the same diode, we can see that in practice \$r_z \approx 12 \Omega\$ for \$ 0\mathrm{mA} < I_z < 10\mathrm{mA}\$ and that \$r_z \approx 2 \Omega\$ for \$ 10\mathrm{mA} < I_z < 20\mathrm{mA}\$.

I'd like to know if I'm reading the datasheet incorrectly or if there's actually a discrepancy in the model used by PSpice and the datasheet values.

[image: V x I relationship for PSpice's model of the ZY91 zener diode in its operating region]

Comment: The response looks a bit clunky/piecemeal. The data sheet says 40 ohms but also hints that it can be as high as 200 ohms. The 40 ohms is a typical figure so, given the upper limit is 5 times higher, it's conceivable that the lower limit might be 5 times lower at 8 ohms.

Comment: I suppose this level of variance would be reasonable to expect from a real diode, but why would a simulation software use such a different value from the one in the specs?

Comment: Poor model? What's your sweeptime?

Comment: I'm not sure since this wasn't simulated, it's the model that PSpice uses for the simulation. You can access the graph by right-clicking the component and clicking Edit PSpice Model > Tools > Extract parameters.

Answer (score 0):

[image: zy91]

.MODEL ZY91 D (IS=15n N=2.22 BV=90.7 RZ=160 IBV=1.4m RS=15 CJ0=51p VJ=750m MJ=330m FC=500m TT=100n EG=1.11 XTI=3)